Generic Bindable Property C# .Net
I'm new to MVVM but I saw that data binding is vital for this pattern. I'm not using any type of framework that has data binding to help with this so I made this class to make a binding system. It's very simple, it doesn't use reflection and it only relies on methods callbacks, like for the setter and the binds.
using System;

[Serializable]
public sealed class BindableProperty<T> : IDisposable, IReadonlyBindableProperty<T>
{
    private T _value;

    private Action<T> _valueChangedDelegate;

    public T GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

     public void Bind(Action<T> ValueChangedCallback)
     {
        _valueChangedDelegate += ValueChangedCallback;
     }

     public void Unbind(Action<T> ValueChangedCallback)
     {
        _valueChangedDelegate -= ValueChangedCallback;
     }

    public void Initialize(ref Action<T> SetterMethod)
    {
        SetterMethod = PropertySetter;
    }

    private void PropertySetter(T Value)
    {
        _value = Value;

        _valueChangedDelegate?.Invoke(Value);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _valueChangedDelegate = null;

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

I also made a readonly interface to help expose these properties
  public interface IReadonlyBindableProperty<T>
  {
      T GetValue();

      void Bind(Action<T> ValueChangedCallback);

      void Unbind(Action<T> ValueChangedCallback);
  }



Have you looked into MSDN C# Data Binding How-To?   I quote:  ... and introduce solutions to related design difficulties encountered when developing applications using MVVM.

I'll take a look, but I'm personally not a big fan of INotifyPropertyChanged

Bind() -> Is the if null guard necessary? Delegate.Combine is tolerant of null and will combine all non-null arguments in any case; returns null if all arguments are null.

not really necessary. I actually did some changes and replaced the Delegate with a generic Action, so now the bind/unbind methods are simpler, and also removed the boxing operation from the DynamicInvoke

The original code under review should never be altered. Otherwise readers cannot assess answers and comments. Such responses will become confusing and even wrong.  Other readers may have insights about "is the null guard necessary" but without the complete, original context it becomes non-sequitur version control  jigsaw puzzle.

sry about that.
